# Highcharts not draw with JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

the problem is that the chart doesn't draw anything when the JSON response is obtained, the code is below:

```
var opciones = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            renderTo: 'charterContainer'
        }, 
        series: []
    };
    var json;
    $.get( "graficas.php?query="+data+"&rutas="+seleccion_rutas+"&residuos="+seleccion_residuos+"", function( tabla_conteo ) {
        console.log(tabla_conteo);
        json = jQuery.parseJSON(tabla_conteo);
        var newSeriesData = {
            name: json['1'].name,
            data: json['1'].data
        };
        opciones.series.push(newSeriesData);            
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opciones);
```

And the JSON response is:

```
{"1": { "name": "Jesus Emilio Ramirez ", "data":[ 111,127,308,262,0]},"2": { "name": "Bioterio ", "data":[ 0,391,0,359,284]}}
```

But if the data is introduced manually into the 'opciones' variable, the chart draws, so I believe that is a problem with the push or format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

Put chart creation inside your `$.get()` callback:

```
$.get( "graficas.php?query="+data+"&rutas="+seleccion_rutas+"&residuos="+seleccion_residuos+"", function( tabla_conteo ) {
        console.log(tabla_conteo);
        json = jQuery.parseJSON(tabla_conteo);
        var newSeriesData = {
            name: json['1'].name,
            data: json['1'].data
        };
        opciones.series.push(newSeriesData);  
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opciones);           
    });
```